# Perl - Read XML

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

**XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<employee>
<name>Smith</name>
<age>43</age>
<sex>M</sex>
<department role='manager'>Operations</department>
</employee>
```

**Perl**

```
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;
$xml = new XML::Simple;
foreach my $data1 ($data = $xml->XMLin("test.xml")) {
print Dumper($data1);
}
```

Above code managed to all the xml value like this.
**Output**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'department' => {
                            'content' => 'Operations',
                            'role' => 'manager'
                          },
          'name' => 'John Doe',
          'sex' => 'M',
          'age' => '43'
        };
```

How do I do, if I only want to get the role value. For this example I need to get **Role => manager**. Any advice or reference link is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So all you need is that value?

```
print $data->{department}{role};
```

Even though [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aSimple) can do the job for simple xml reading, I'd recommend that you use a better module like [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) or [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aTwig):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);

for my $role ($xml->findnodes('//@role')) {
    print $role->value;
}

__DATA__
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<employee>
<name>Smith</name>
<age>43</age>
<sex>M</sex>
<department role='manager'>Operations</department>
</employee>
```

Outputs:

```
manager
```

#### About XPaths

The power the modules `XML::LibXML` and `XML::Twig` comes in their implementation of [`XPath syntax`](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp).  I used the minimal XPath needed to pull the data that you want `'//@role'` to demonstrate how it doesn't need to know the full tree structure like is needed for `XML::Simple`.  That XPath basically just pulls the value of any "role" attribute at any level.

As `ikegami` pointed out, it would probably be wise to make the XPath more limiting, such as `'//department/@role'` or `'//employee/department/@role'`.  Or even more likely, you'll iterate on all employees and then pull the desired data.

```
for my $employee ($xml->findnodes('//employee')) {
    print $employee->findvalue('//department/@role')
}
```

For further examples of XPaths, just check the w3schools link above or [`XPath Examples`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Finally, to find additional ways of loading the DOM, just check out [`XML::LibXML::Parser`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aLibXML%3a%3aParser)

Comment: It seems to me the `role` attribute is probably optional. If so the XML::"Simple" solution would probably be `ref($data->{department}) ? $data->{department}{role} : undef`

Comment: `//department/@role` and `/employee/department/@role` would be safer

Comment: Agreed, that was the minimal XPath.  For further examples, the OP can check out: [`XPath Examples`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: how do i change <DATA> to my xml file. I try to replace <DATA> to test.xml but throwing me `Bareword "test" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at readxml1.cgi line 8.
Bareword "xml" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at readxml1.cgi line 8.
Execution of readxml1.cgi aborted due to compilation errors.`

Comment: @chinna_82: You should change the `load_xml` call to `XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'test.xml')`

Comment: @Miller, `->load_xml(IO => \*DATA)`

Comment: @ikegami Yeah, I use the `string => ` format by default for two reasons.  One, it's the one I believe would be the easiest for the generic OP to use without having to check the documentation for additional constructor formats.  And two, it's the one I have solidly memorized without having to look at the [`docs`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Parser) myself.  :)

Answer (score 0):

With XML::Twig:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers =>  # in the handler $_ is the department element
                  { department => sub { print $_->att( 'role'), "\n"; } })
         ->parsefile( 'test.xml');
```

Comment: this only return role attribute.. how bout other elements? Please advice.

Comment: which elements? Please be more specific ;--)

Comment: the department would be the text of the element, so it would be `$_->text` in the handler

Answer (score 0):

There is a very helpful tool called **XMLStarlet** i used it to parse xml files with Perl and shell scripts.
in your case : this command do the job :

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/employee/department" -m "@role" -v . -n your_file_name.xml
```

you can assign the output to a variable :

```
your_variable =`xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/employee/department" -m "@role" -v . -n your_file_name.xml`
```

for documentation : have a look on this link : [XMLStarlet Documentation](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch03s01.html)